# How to create new product attribute with file type?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

I have one question : Magento 2 doesn't support attribute with file type ?
I tried create new product attribute with file type but i can't see :
[image]
Anyone can help me ?

Comment: do you want to image up loader attribute ?

Comment: No, i want file upload such as pdf or txt file

Comment: Then use some thing like this module https://github.com/Sebwite/Magento2-Product-Downloads it will map products with pdf etc

Comment: sure use it , it will help you

Comment: most welcome @PYYick